# How to combine multiple this.expect statements

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, pageobjects

I would like to create a single method of verifying that all of the landing page objects are present before performing the next test step. Below is what I currently have but am looking for a cleaner way to accomplish this. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
verifyLandingPageNavElements:function(){
    this.expect.element('@NavLogo_img')
    .to.be.present.after(2000),
    this.expect.element('@BuySearch_nav')
    .to.be.present.after(2000),
    this.expect.element('@Sell_nav')
    .to.be.present.after(2000),
    this.expect.element('@Appraise_nav')
    .to.be.present.after(2000),
    this.expect.element('@Products_nav')
    .to.be.present.after(2000),
    this.expect.element('@LocateADealer_nav')
    .to.be.present.after(2000)
    this.expect.element('@Search_nav')
    .to.be.present.after(2000)
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good approach would be to create a custom command for that.

```
// ./lib/custom-commands/expectElementsToBePresent.js

exports.command = function(selectors, ms) {
  selectors.forEach(selector => this.expect.element(selector).to.be.present.after(ms));
  return this;
};

// Test case

client
  .url('https://some.url')
  .expectElementsToBePresent([
    '.some.selector',
    '.another.selector'
  ], 2000);
```

Don't forget to point Nightwatch to the directory where you keep your custom commands (`./lib/custom-commands` in my example), by setting `custom_commands_path` property of config file.

If you want to learn more info on custom commands, here is the link to official documentation: http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#writing-custom-commands